# Hibernate many to one delete : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, mapping

Keep am getting ConstraintViolationException while am executing this hibernate many to one delete query...

Here is the program ...

http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-one-mapping-delete-query-example/

Not sure where am doing the mistake ?

Comment: What is the full stacktrace and message of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You try to cascade delete from such a child to parent, that have parent referenced by other childs. That of course fails, as explained behind the link you gave:

> .. provided if that parent object has no other child objects, means if
>   parent has only one child, in this case if we delete child, parent
>   will also got deleted, but in all other cases it will throws exception